# Cygwin cannot load shared library dlllablgtk2

Tags: gtk, cygwin, ocaml

I have installed lablgtk in Cygwin and have compiled an example from this tutorial https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/introduction_to_gtk.html

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -g -package lablgtk2 -linkpkg simple.ml -o simple
```

However when I try to run the program with "run simple", nothing happens. I then compiled again, this time with the output as "simple.exe" and tried running this file with "./simple.exe". Now I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: cannot load shared library dlllablgtk2
Reason: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

It should be noted that I was able to compile and run the program just a couple of days ago. I'm not sure what has changed since then and I'm not sure what to do next.

I do get the following warnings when compiling:

```
File "simple.ml", line 10, characters 2-44:
Warning 10: this expression should have type unit.
File "simple.ml", line 20, characters 2-54:
Warning 10: this expression should have type unit.
File "simple.ml", line 25, characters 2-69:
Warning 10: this expression should have type unit.
```

But this didn't prevent me from running the program previously.
How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Just a guess: are you mismatching 32-bit and 64-bit DLLs?

Comment: It's possible but since it worked before and I haven't changed the DLLs since, I'm not sure which DLLs could be mismatching. Is there any easy way to check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by re-adding MingGW to my path:

```
export PATH=$PATH:"/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/bin"
```

I had done this previously, which is why the executables worked before, but it seems that it didn't save for the next time I logged on. Before, when I hadn't added the path, I wasn't able to install lablgtk and so unable to compile the program, so I was receiving a different error. This time lablgtk was installed, so while compilation was successful, I got a very different error which caused the confusion.